# How to make app in Arabic to properly change navigation bar items in version 8.4?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arabic

I'm working on an app, that can be in English or in Arabic. The issue appears when the app is launched in arabic, running on a 8.4 iPad air, in which case the orientation of the navigation bar items is not changed as it should.

The following code is used for setting the content to the right instead of left:

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_9_0) && defined(ARABIC)
if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
    [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
}
#endif
```

However, it only works for iOS versions 9.0 or greater. How can I force thing to the right with lesser versions?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't, because Apple didn't add serious support for RTL prior to iOS 9 (same for OSX El Capitan). Although if you really really want to, you may have to implement your own navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this on versions prior to iOS 9.

Also, setting `semanticContentAttribute` on `UIView`'s `appearance` proxy is not recommended. Your app should be following the system language, and not something that you define in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll have to figure a way to solve this.

Comment: @ Sergio Bravo Talero
Have you found alternative for iOS 8